# open cart Version 3.0.2.0, (how do i debug with Open cart?)

Tags: php, opencart-3

I have tried to echo/print with  to output something to the console(PHP),  and same attempts in template file( TPL FILE).
BUT none of these works.

I also tried to output variable in to the error.log,(ex

$var = 'this is a variable';

//some other code goes here

$log = new Log('LOG_NAME.log');

$log->write('Is $var a null? Here is the value '

But it did not write anything in to the error.log.

ANY ONE with any solution would be great!!!!!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just want to be able to  console log anything from the source code